# Switch to specific tab in Vim like in Firefox?

Tags: vim

How do I make Vim switch to a certain tab when I hit Alt+# ?  For example, to get to the third tab, I'd hit Alt+3 (like the behavior in Firefox).

Edit: also, how can I make Control + tab == gt, Control + shift + tab == gT

Answer (score 8):

```
:nmap <M-1> :tabnext 1<CR>
:nmap <M-2> :tabnext 2<CR>
etc.
```

See `:h :tabnext`.  Note that by default you can also do `Ngt` in normal mode where N is the number of the tab you want (starting with 1).

Comment: Hm, this doesn't actually work for me...I'm not sure why. The Ngt tip is nice though.

Comment: <M-1>, <M-2> etc. conflict with window manager key bindings on my system, but it seemed to work OK otherwise.  <M-9> was unmapped and I tried that and it worked.  What kind of problem are you having?

Comment: I'm not sure...it just doesn't end up doing anything. I also don't think I have anything bound to those keys otherwise wouldn't the Firefox shortcuts not work either? I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure either... worked OK in KDE, and I just tried it in Windows, copy/pasted from my post and it worked OK too.  I'm doing this in gvim; if you're doing it in console vim, your terminal may not be allowing Vim to see Alt+N keypresses.

Comment: Depending on how your system is setup, it's possible that <M-1> only works for the left ALT.  Did you try with both ALTs?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me (copied and pasted from my rc):

```
" Tab Control (others)
 map <A-1> 1gt
 map <A-2> 2gt
 map <A-3> 3gt
 map <A-4> 4gt
 map <A-5> 5gt
 map <A-6> 6gt
 map <A-7> 7gt
 map <A-8> 8gt
 map <A-9> 9gt
```

Also further goodness:

```
map <C-Right> <ESC>:tabnext<CR>
map <C-Left> <ESC>:tabprev<CR>
map <C-t> <ESC>:tabnew<CR>
```

You may want to change it to nmap like the example above to restrict the usage a little better I've been a bit lazy in that respect.

Missed your edit next tab with Ctl-t would be:

```
map <C-t> :tabnext<CR>
```

I don't think the tabprevious mapping is possible in vim due to the way it handles uppercase  characters see:

http://www.nabble.com/Maping-Ctrl-Shift-s-problems-td22918941.html

To save some time I spent hunting around when I wanted this

Comment: Its not working for me . (I wrongly upvoted it and Now I am unable to undo it) 
I used this instead - 
    map <F1> 1gt   
    map <F2> 2gt   
    map <F3> 3gt   
    map <F4> 4gt   
    map <F5> 5gt

Answer (score 1):

Getting this to work in urxvt proved difficult. Eventually I settled on using the folowing bindings:

```
:nnoremap <Esc>1 gt1
:nnoremap <Esc>2 gt2
:nnoremap <Esc>3 gt3
:nnoremap <Esc>4 gt4
:nnoremap <Esc>5 gt5
:nnoremap <Esc>6 gt6
:nnoremap <Esc>7 gt7
:nnoremap <Esc>8 gt8
:nnoremap <Esc>9 gt9
:nnoremap <Esc>0 gt0
```

The problem was that Alt number combinations get bound to escape prefixed numbers by default in rxvt. Originally I managed by having the following in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
:nnoremap <M-1> gt1
:nnoremap <M-2> gt2
...
```

This was made to work by using the following to '~/.Xdefaults':

```
URxvt*meta8: true
```

This forces rxvt to use the 8th character bit when Alt is pressed, which is what Vim uses to detect the Alt state. Setting this in your `.Xdefaults` file enables the 8th bit to be set. However, this causes problems in other programs, such as `irssi` running over `screen`, hence my suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you may want use the cmd + number to switch tabs. The following works well.

```
map <D-1> 1gt 
map <D-2> 2gt 
map <D-3> 3gt
etc...
```